# Get all token holders of a token (mint)

Tags: spl-token, web3.js

I want to know for a given `mint` what are all the token holders?
I know about`getTokenLargestAccounts` but want it without the top 20 cap?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Code copied from a discord message [here](https://discord.com/channels/428295358100013066/517163444747894795/893537266184630324).

What happens is

- You do the RPC call `getProgramAccounts` for the token program
- then filter for accounts with the length of a token account
- then filter for accounts with the mint address / public key of your desired mint

  - `"bytes": "token mint address here"`

```
curl http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed",
        "filters": [
          {
            "dataSize": 165
          },
          {
            "memcmp": {
              "offset": 0,
              "bytes": "token mint address here"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }'
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark as solved if the code actually works for you. I haven't actually run it but it looks approximately correct; the program Id and dataSize of the token account are both right, so is the offset.